# Cache is not getting updated in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching

I'm using Spring Boot @CachePut and @Cacheable annotations to cache the data.

```
@CachePut(value = "cache1", key = "#clientId")
public Map<String, Object> buildCache(Long clientId){
Map<String, Object> cacheMap= new HashMap<String, Object>();
//get values from remote db and store them in the local db as well as cache
return cacheMap;
}

@Cacheable(value = "cache1", key = "#clientId")
public Map<String, Object> getFromCache(Long clientId){
     //get from local db
}
```

In buildCache, I get the values from remote DB and save those values in the local DB and cache. In getCache method, I get the values from local DB. When I invoked the getCache method the first time, it gets executed and local DB values get saved in cache.Then I called the buildCache method to update the cache as well as local DB values. After that, I called getCache method again to get the updated values. But this method still returns the old values instead of new ones

In short, to refresh the cache, I execute @CachePut method. But I do not get the updated value when i call the @Cacheable method.

Please tell me where am i going wrong.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. what do you meant by not getting reflected.

Comment: @pvpkiran Sorry for the confusion. I've updated my post.

Comment: is cacheMap declared at class level or function level(inside buildCache ). what do you have in getFromCache method?

Comment: @pvpkiran cacheMap is a local variable. it is declared and used inside the method. In buildCache, i get the values from remote db and save those values in the local db and cache. In getCache method, i get the values from local db. 
when i invoked the getCache method the first time, it gets executed and local db values get saved in cache.Then i called the buildCache method to update the cache as well as local db values. After that, i called getCache method again to get the updated values. But this method  still returns old values instead of updated ones.

Comment: I think you are getting confused with `@Cacheable` and `@CachePut`.  The  scenarios you want will work only if you have a common variable between those two methods. It would be better if you put more code. check an example here for better understanding https://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-cacheput-annotation-example-using-javaconfig

Answer (score 0):

```
@CacheEvict(value ="user" ,allEntries = true)
@CachePut(value = "user",key = "#userDTO.id")
@PostMapping("user/update")
public List<User> updateUser(@RequestBody UserDTO userDTO){
    return userService.updateUser(userDTO);
}
```

First Delete the existing cache then update so that next time first fetch will be from DB and then it will store in cache and fetch from the cache.